# Given a vector, how to scale to a given length and find components?

Tags: vectors

Given a vector $\overrightarrow v = <a,b,c>$ of length $l_0$,

How would one scale that vector to a desired length $l$ and find its components again?

Answer (score 1):

You can take $\vec{v'} = \left\langle \dfrac{la}{l_0},\dfrac{lb}{l_0},\dfrac{lc}{l_0}\right\rangle$, then $|\vec{v'}| = l$, and the components were shown.